# torch.distributed fails on cluster (all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable)

Tags: pytorch, distributed-computing

I would like to run `torch.distributed` on a HPC cluster. The command I'm using is the following:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node 2 train.py
```

I'm using two NVIDIA Quadro RTX 6000 GPUs with 24 GB of memory. `train.py` is a Python script and uses Huggingface Trainer to fine-tune a transformer model.

I'm getting the error shown below. Does somebody know how this can be solved?

```
/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py:178: FutureWarning: The module torch.distributed.launch is deprecated
and will be removed in future. Use torchrun.
Note that --use_env is set by default in torchrun.
If your script expects `--local_rank` argument to be set, please
change it to read from `os.environ['LOCAL_RANK']` instead. See 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#launch-utility for 
further instructions

  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cluster/home/username/chatbot/gpt_j/train.py", line 294, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/cluster/home/username/chatbot/gpt_j/train.py", line 64, in main
    model = Model()
  File "/cluster/home/username/chatbot/gpt_j/model.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.model.to(self.device)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 907, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 578, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 578, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 578, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 601, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 905, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
2022-08-20 02:34:24,834 WARNING:Using custom data configuration default-990e072ab094d8c6
Fatal error condition occurred in /opt/vcpkg/buildtrees/aws-c-io/src/9e6648842a-364b708815.clean/source/event_loop.c:72: aws_thread_launch(&cleanup_thread, s_event_loop_destroy_async_thread_fn, el_group, &thread_options) == AWS_OP_SUCCESS
Exiting Application
################################################################################
Stack trace:
################################################################################
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x200af06) [0x2ae499958f06]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x20028e5) [0x2ae4999508e5]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x1f27e09) [0x2ae499875e09]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x200ba3d) [0x2ae499959a3d]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x1f25948) [0x2ae499873948]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x200ba3d) [0x2ae499959a3d]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x1ee0b46) [0x2ae49982eb46]
/cluster/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow.so.900(+0x194546a) [0x2ae49929346a]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x39ce9) [0x2ae49001fce9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x39d37) [0x2ae49001fd37]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfc) [0x2ae49000855c]
/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/bin/python() [0x4006fe]
2022-08-20 02:34:24,947 WARNING:Reusing dataset text (/cluster/home/username/.cache/huggingface/datasets/text/default-990e072ab094d8c6/0.0.0/21a506d1b2b34316b1e82d0bd79066905d846e5d7e619823c0dd338d6f1fa6ad)

  0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
100%|â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  3.57it/s]
100%|â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  3.56it/s]
2022-08-20 02:34:25,663 WARNING:Using custom data configuration default-e89076d74da83269
2022-08-20 02:34:25,669 WARNING:Reusing dataset text (/cluster/home/username/.cache/huggingface/datasets/text/default-e89076d74da83269/0.0.0/21a506d1b2b34316b1e82d0bd79066905d846e5d7e619823c0dd338d6f1fa6ad)

  0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
100%|â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  9.74it/s]
100%|â–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆâ–ˆ| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  9.71it/s]
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 787650
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 262548
    })
})
WARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 123732 closing signal SIGTERM
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: -6) local_rank: 0 (pid: 123731) of binary: /cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/bin/python
/cluster/shadow/.lsbatch/1660955521.229195199: line 8: 123724 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node 2 train.py
```

Edit: Using `faulthandler` I'm getting the following additional output:

```
WARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 61051 closing signal SIGTERM
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: -6) local_rank: 1 (pid: 61052) of binary: /cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/bin/python
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00002abf0c0dc040 (most recent call first):
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/utils/store.py", line 31 in get_all
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/utils/store.py", line 53 in synchronize
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/utils/store.py", line 67 in barrier
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 906 in _exit_barrier
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 877 in _invoke_run
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/agent/server/api.py", line 709 in run
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/metrics/api.py", line 125 in wrapper
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 236 in launch_agent
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 131 in __call__
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 715 in run
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 174 in launch
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 189 in main
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 193 in <module>
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86 in _run_code
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-8.2.0/python/3.10.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196 in _run_module_as_main

Extension modules: torch._C, torch._C._fft, torch._C._linalg, torch._C._nn, torch._C._sparse, torch._C._special, numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator (total: 19)
/cluster/shadow/.lsbatch/1661033358.229240672: line 8: 61028 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python -q -X faulthandler -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node 2 train.py
```

Comment: you can trace back seg faults with the python's [`faulthandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html), it should give you some pointers.

Comment: @ndrwnaguib I was running it with faulthandler and edited my post with the additional information.